# Multiselect drop down

Tags: php, drop-down-menu, multi-select

I have a PHP question. I am trying to alter some code that a partner of mine wrote (he has since then left and cannot be contacted) but I am not hugely familiar with PHP. I believe that the question will be fairly simple but I am not sure where to start. Currently there is a drop down menu that allows you to select only one option. I BELIEVE the code that is involved in that process is here:

```
<select id='List' style='width:75px' onchange='displayEx(this);'>
    <option value="0">list</option>

    <?php
    foreach ($LIST as $list)
    {
        echo "<option value='$list'>$list</option>";
    }
    echo "</select>";
    ?>   
<select id='selectd' style='width:75px'>
        <option value="0">X</option>
        </select>
        <input id="addTest" type="button" value="Add" onclick="addTest();"/>
        <p id='error_display' style="height:10px;"></p>
        <div>
            <?php
                $i = 1;
                foreach ($Groups as $G)
                {
                echo "<div style='float:left;width:30%;height:100px;display:inline'><p id='Group $i' title='$G'>Group $G:</p><p id='display_Group_$i'>0/94</p><input id=\"get_Group_$i\" type=\"button\" value=\"Create\" onclick=\"createSheet($i);\" disabled = \"true\" style=\" vertical-align:bottom; display:inline;\"/></div>";
                $i++;
                }
            ?>
        </div>
```

But I am not sure what to do with it. I was thinking something like this...

```
foreach ($select as $value)  
{  
    echo '<option';  
    if (isset($_POST['select']) && $_POST['select'] == $value)  
    SOMETHING HERE
}
```

I don't know though. Other peoples code can sometimes be so confusing (particularly in a language you aren't the best at). For my sanity I hope someone can help me puzzle this out but even if someone could help me translate the current code I would be super grateful.

Comment: Are you asking how to populate the select box or what todo with it once the form has been posted?

Comment: Both I guess? I have a drop down box already so I assume that it can stay without too much alteration. I need to be able to select more than one and then submit them all rather than just the original one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use multiselect for the select tag

```
 <select multiple="multiple">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I am sorry, as I mentioned I don't have incredible strength in this language. Could you explain? Do you just mean change anything with <select id... to <select multiple...?

Comment: Just add multiple='multiple' in your select tag where you want multiple selections

Comment: if you want to use some fancy multiselect drop down then have a look at http://quasipartikel.at/multiselect/

Comment: Ah! I see. That does allow me to select more than one, but when I submit only the first that I clicked gets added, not all of the selected. Any suggestions on that?

Comment: Fancy isn't required, but I will check those links for sure!

Comment: change echo "<option value='$list[]'>$list</option>"; let me know if it works

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ']', expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING... is returned when I add the [] to that line. :/

Comment: can you tell me what you want to de when you select multiple option ? U sbmit a form ? or call a javascript_

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15962/discussion-between-user-and-umair-iqbal)